# Searching Date Field value in ElasticSearch without time

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I have one date field in my data as

```
"type": "date",
"format": "dateOptionalTime"
```

Now My date Field and Value is -

```
"INITIAL_EXTRACT_DATE" : "2015-04-02T06:47:57.78+05:30"
```

While searching I am searching based on only date that is "2015-04-02".
but I am getting 0 result.

Can anyone suggest how to search exact date and is any of date.

Now I am trying with this -

**For Exact Date** -

```
"term": {
          "IH_PT_DSC": {
             "value": "2015-04-02"
          }
       }
```

**For Is any of date** -

```
"terms": {
         "IH_PT_DSC": [
            "2015-04-02",
            "2015-04-03",
            "2015-04-03"
         ]
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`range` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html) for this, by using the same date in `gte` / `lte` and a `format` parameter where you only specify the date part (i.e. leave out the time part)

```
{
    "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "range" : {
                "IH_PT_DSC" : {
                    "gte": "2015-04-02",
                    "lte": "2015-04-02",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to specify multiple dates, you can do so easily as well.

```
{
    "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "range" : {
                "IH_PT_DSC" : {
                    "gte": "2015-04-01",
                    "lte": "2015-04-03",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if you need to query disjoint date intervals, simply use a `bool/should` filter:

```
{
  "constant_score": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "range": {                    <--- interval 1
              "IH_PT_DSC": {
                "gte": "2015-04-01",
                "lte": "2015-04-03",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {                    <--- interval 2
              "IH_PT_DSC": {
                "gte": "2015-04-05",
                "lte": "2015-04-08",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {                    <--- interval 3
              "IH_PT_DSC": {
                "gte": "2015-04-10",
                "lte": "2015-04-12",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should indeed use a [date range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html), and a format parameter (but much simpler as explained in the previous answer)

**For Exact Date**

```
{
 "range": {
  "IH_PT_DSC": {
   "value": {
    "gte": "2015-04-02||/d",
    "lte": "2015-04-02||/d"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**For Is any of date -**
use a boolean filter and "should" the different blocks together

```
{
 "bool": {
  "should": [{
    "range": {
     "IH_PT_DSC": {
      "value": {
       "gte": "2015-04-02||/d",
       "lte": "2015-04-02||/d"
      }
     }
    }
   }, {
    "range": {
     "IH_PT_DSC": {
      "value": {
       "gte": "2015-06-07||/d",
       "lte": "2015-06-07||/d"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```